# Passing props in react - fetching

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I'm simply trying to pass props through components and render it in jsx but somehow that wouldn't work. I was searching for the problem but just cannot find it.

I'm trying pass props from this component:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/Products.css";
import ProductItem from "../items/ProductItem";
class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("../products.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.products }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="products-container">
        <ProductItem data={this.state.data[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Products;
```

to this component:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/ProductItem.css";
const ProductItem = props => {
  console.log(props.data, "current");
  return (
    <div className="product-item">
      <img src="" alt="" className="bike-image" />
      <div className="active-product" />
      <div className="view-details">Compare</div>
      <h2>Bike</h2>
      <h4>downhill bike</h4>
      <p>3500 PLN</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ProductItem;
```

And the problem is when I'm looking in my `react dev tools`, props has passed properly, but when I'm trying to get to attributes of the object like `props.data.id`, I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: did you try to console.log props.data only?

Comment: yes, i've got whole object, and its works properly

Comment: and in object you have ID correct?

Comment: That's right. But I can't read any attributes from this object

Comment: in the ProductItem component you console.log(props.data), could you please attach some screenshot of that console.log.

Comment: https://imgur.com/6cwnpqI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` needs some time to get the response and populate the `this.state.data` array. So you need to check if the `this.state.data[0]` value is really available or not. You can try this-

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="products-container">
       {this.state.data && this.state.data.length > 0 &&  <ProductItem data={this.state.data[0]} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!